# How do I retrieve the song list in this fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-contentprovider

There are two errors neither of which I can figure out why.

1. Cannot resolve method "`getContentResolver()`"

2.Cannot infer arguments (on the `new ArrayAdapter<>()`).

I hope this is the right way to get the songs list from a `fragment`? If there is some better alternative, please explain that. Thank you

```
public class SongsFragment extends Fragment {

    public SongsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_songs, container, false);
        ListView audioView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.songView);
        ArrayList<String> audioList = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};
        final Cursor audioCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, null, null, null);

        if (audioCursor != null) {
            if (audioCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    int audioIndex = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);

                    audioList.add(audioCursor.getString(audioIndex));
                } while (audioCursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        audioCursor.close();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, audioList);
        audioView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: will you not downvote it please? Just put a comment telling me why you want to do that? Do you have any idea how extremely frustrating it is for a relatively new user on stack to wait for 8 days before being able to ask another question because a bunch of super users love downvoting?

Comment: When you are using fragment you need getActivtiy() method to use Activity things. So just put getActivtiy( in front of getContentResolver.

Comment: and also replace 'this' with getActivity()

Answer (score 1):

In class which is extending `Fragment` Context is not available to get it need to use `getActivity()` method.

**1.** *Cannot resolve method "getContentResolver()"*

Because `getContentResolver` method is not available in `Fragment` class, need to user Context to access it:

```
 final Cursor audioCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                              MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                              proj, null, null, null);
```

**2.** *Cannot infer arguments (on the new ArrayAdapter<>()).*

Because  `ArrayAdapter` constructor require valid `Context` as first parameter :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), 
                                         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                                         android.R.id.text1, audioList);
```